# Terminate bad dask worker

Tags: dask

Can a dask worker signal the scheduler that it was setup incorrectly?

I'm hitting a problem where my worker is being setup incorrectly some small fraction of the time.  The worker errors out and brings down my whole graph.  (It's not the task -- it's the worker itself that is bad.)   I know the symptom and can catch it, and would like the worker to say "hey scheduler, remove me as a worker -- do not use it".

I am using dask-gateway, if that matters.

In case it helps, the workers (seems to be a few percent) do not have access to  libcuda.so.1:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cellpose/models.py in <module>
      8 import cv2
      9 
---> 10 from mxnet import gluon, nd
     11 import mxnet as mx
     12 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mxnet/__init__.py in <module>
     22 from __future__ import absolute_import
     23 
---> 24 from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
     25 from . import engine
     26 from .base import MXNetError

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mxnet/context.py in <module>
     22 import warnings
     23 import ctypes
---> 24 from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
     25 from .base import _LIB
     26 from .base import check_call

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mxnet/base.py in <module>
    212 __version__ = libinfo.__version__
    213 # library instance of mxnet
--> 214 _LIB = _load_lib()
    215 
    216 # type definitions

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mxnet/base.py in _load_lib()
    203     """Load library by searching possible path."""
    204     lib_path = libinfo.find_lib_path()
--> 205     lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
    206     # DMatrix functions
    207     lib.MXGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__()
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do what you want with a [WorkerPlugin](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/custom-startup.html).
Though I would argue you don't want to do this.  Worker initialization *should* work every time and you should fix the root cause here.
Given issues with libcuda and dask-gateway you might be interested in this dask-gateway issue: https://github.com/dask/dask-gateway/issues/177

Comment: The low-level setup is out of my control -- the cuda libraries are missing on a few percent of my GKE pods setup with on nodes with Google's nvidia installer daemonset.  I haven't tried the dask-cuda stuff, as I just roll my own images based on nvidia/cuda and just have 1 GPU per pod/worker.
I'll check out WorkerPlugin, though I don't quite what context the code is run in.  I may have to actually talk to the cluster (not just the scheduler) and tell a node to go way if a "import mxnet" fails.